# Creating OleDBConnection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am migrating code from VS2010 to VS2013 and my syntax in VS2010 shows compile errors in 13?!?  Can someone assist me with why these two compile errors are being thrown?

```
Syntax error, ',' expected
{ expected
```

And this is the syntax that works w/o issue in 10.

```
    public static string DCAVACA(string badTable)
    {
        olecon = new OleDbConnection(OLECONN)
        {
            olecon.Open();
            deleteTable = new string[1] { "badTable" };
            for (int q = deleteTable.GetLowerBound(0); q <= deleteTable.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DROP TABLE " + deleteTable[q], olecon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is invalid syntax in both versions.  You're missing semicolongs, and your braces don't make sense.

Comment: @SLaks that is a direct copy/paste from my VS10 project that compiles and runs error free

Comment: Then you're utilizing some bug in the C# compiler (which seems extremely unlikely).  Every statement must end in a semicolon, including variable declarations.

Comment: Why does the method even return anything at all? (It's always going to be `null` unless an Exception occurs.) Why have a (overly complicated) for loop over a `string[1]` (was `string[2]` initialized with 1 element before the edit)? What about SQL injection (yes, there can be "worse" things than dropping specified tables, ie. getting access to secret data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that syntax should work in any version of Visual Studio tbh. FWIW, I think you want to use the `using` statement:

```
    public static string DCAVACA(string badTable)
    {
        using (var olecon = new OleDbConnection(OLECONN)) // only change required for *syntactic* reasons
        {
            olecon.Open();
            deleteTable = new string[1] { "badTable" };
            for (int q = deleteTable.GetLowerBound(0); q <= deleteTable.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DROP TABLE " + deleteTable[q], olecon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

There are some other issues with the code in general (`badTable` variable is not used at all, `deleteTable` is useless as a static `string[2]`, naming, etc.), but that's out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after `olecon = new OleDbConnection(OLECONN)`.

Braces after a "new" are used to set attributes/properties of the newly-created object, not to run other arbitrary code. If this truly does run in VS2010, I have no idea why.